Example for necessity of a condition in Riesz representation theorem
The Riesz representation theorem I'm referring to is the Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem
The proof given in Rudin's book assumes both measures satisfy inner and outer regularity, and uses the fact that the values taken on compact sets determine the measure to deduce uniqueness. I was wondering if there's an example for two measures which both represent a linear functional on $C_{c}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, which are not the same. This means one of them must fail to satisfy inner or outer regularity, but I can't seem to come up with an example.
